# how to center ui icon in jquery ui button

Tags: css, image, jquery-ui, button

I'm looking for a way to create toolbar buttons uisng jquery ui.

I tried to create button using

```
<div id='menubar_home' style='vertical-align: middle;width: 20px; height: 20px;'>
</div>
```

and using

```
$('#menubar_home').button({
    icons: { primary: "ui-icon-home" }
});
```

But image in button is not centered:

[image: not centered]

How to center image in button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#menubar_home {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume there isn't transparent sides in the image.

Adds a border to `img` to work on positioning: `border: 1px solid red;`

Then check the image has a `display: block;` property.

Try to add `margin: 0 auto;` property, which aims to center a block (your image).

You will perhaps need to add `!important` to force the property: `margin: 0 auto !important;`

Hoping to help you (not sure, not easy without manipulating the code myself).

Answer (score 0):

Add a `padding:8px;` to the button/input style to allow the icon to be properly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

**You could also place a span within the div like so:**

```
<div id="menu-bar-home">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span>
</div>
```

**reference it in css and change the position:**

```
div#menu-bar-home {
    position:relative;
}
div#menu-bar-home > span {
    position: absolute;
    left: +or-(n)px; /* so just adjust the position
}
```

also note you may have to adjust the z-index of the span.

best o' luck, bro.

### EDIT: you may still achieve the results you want in this manner, but I though you were creating the button with the div.

As the gentleman below suggests, I would set the css for menu bar as such:

```
div#menu-bar-home
{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following in CSS:

```
#menubar_home {
   font-size: 0; 
   width: 23px; top: 5; 
   height: 23px;
}
```